# ES6 module/namespacing syntax

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use [grunt-es6-module-transpiler](https://github.com/joefiorini/grunt-es6-module-transpiler) to write some JS modules. I'd like to be able to do something like `LJ.Config.api.url` and `LJ.Geo.geocode()`, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out the correct syntax.

Here's an example of what I've got so far:

```
module 'LJ/Config' {
  api: {
    url: 'http://example.com/'
  }
}

module 'LJ/Geo' {
  geocode: function () {
    /* do stuff. */
  }
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Have a look at the article the [readme](https://github.com/joefiorini/grunt-es6-module-transpiler/blob/master/README.md) links to: [Using Grunt & the ES6 Module Transpiler](http://www.thomasboyt.com/2013/06/21/es6-module-transpiler). It shows the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at that article, but it doesn't explain how to do the module namespacing I'm going for here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400098/using-nested-classes-to-simulate-namespaces-in-es6 provides some helpful ideas for creating namespaces.