# Using nested classes to simulate namespaces in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a file, `Services.js` which I am trying to load all of my individual services in. These are exposed as singletons.

`Services.js`

```
var Services = { };

export default Services;
```

I then want Sample Service nested under Services, so I could invoke for example `Services.Sample.Operation()`

`SampleService.js'

```
import Services from './Services';

Services.Sample = {

    Operation: function() {
        alert('operation!') 
    }
};

export default Services.Sample;
```

Then, I try and import:

```
import Services from './services/Services';
import SampleService from './services/SampleService';

alert(Services);         // yields '[object object]'
alert(SampleService);    // yields '[object object]'
alert(Services.Sample);  // yields 'undefined' <--- This is the one I actually want to use
```

How can I get it so I can refer to Services.Sample rather tan SampleService. How can I make SampleService become nested under Services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way doesn't work because you're importing `Services.js` in `SampleService.js`, but the `Services` variable is not the 'original' `Services` variable from `Services.js`.

What I'd do is something like this:

`SampleService.js`:

```
SampleService = {

    Operation: function() {
        alert('operation!') 
    }
};

export default SampleService;
```

`Services.js`:

```
import SampleService from './SampleService';

var Services = { };
Services.Sample = SampleService;

export default Services;
```

and then:

```
import Services from './services/Services';

alert(Services);         
alert(Services.Sample);

export default Services;
```

This does also seem to make more sense to me regarding basic (in)dependencies and consistency of your modules (define what `Services` can do in `Services.js` not `SampleService.js`, `SampleService` could be independent of `Services`, the module loading `Services.js` should not depend on `SampleService.js` as well as that might change later, ...).